# paper-input change event not fired when setting value

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I add an `eventListener` for the `change-event`  to a bunch of `paper-inputs`.

Now when I change manually (by click or typing) the `value` of the `paper-input` the `event` fires as expected, but when I set the `value` through code, the zero is visible inside the `input` but the `event` doesn't fire.

**Code:**

```
for(var i = 0; i<this.children.length; i++){
  this.children[i].children[0].set('value',0);
  this.children[i].children[0].addEventListener('change', function(e){
    e.detail = {"name" : e.srcElement.name,
                "value": e.srcElement.value
               }
    pushToChecked(e);
  })
}
```

I call the following function to reset all my inputs when needed:

```
_setToZero : function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<this.children.length; i++){
    this.children[i].children[0].set('value',0);//should fire change-event  
  }
}
```

`this.children[i]` looks like this:

```
<div class="obj-input">
  <paper-input class="paper-number" type="number" min="0" name="test">
  </paper-input>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Just ask me if you need to see more code.

Answer (score 3):

Typical `<input>` does not fire `change` event when `value` is changed from code, so I believe `<paper-element>` is expressing the platform behavior.

However, `<paper-element>` will fire (non-bubbling) `value-changed` event that you can use instead.

```html
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>

  <x-example></x-example>

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-input placeholder="input" on-change="change" on-value-changed="valueChanged" value="{{value}}"></paper-input>
    <button on-tap="changeValue">Change Value</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    // only need this when in the main document and on non-Chrome
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-example',
        changeValue: function() {
          this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        },
        change: function() {
          console.log('got _change_ event');
        },
        valueChanged: function() {
          console.log('got _value-changed_ event');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note: check the console to see the events fire if you run the snippet.